# Catch the selection of the values in select/drop-down-box prior to the node submission

Tags: 7, hooks

I have a Drupal 7 custom module with a couple of select/drop-down-boxes.  Is there a hook to catch the selection of the values in those boxes prior to the submission of the content node?  I am looking for a hook before the hook_node_submit occurs.

Thanks, 
Derek

Comment: With an ajax callback on your form you can catch whatever, whenever you want prior to submission. The form validate functions fire first, you could always inject another custom form_submit function into the form to handle your own custom processing (and probably adjust your modules weight to come prior to the parent content type as needed).

Comment: Why exactly would you need that?

Comment: I want to call some custom db function to get back values and create a radio-button list dynamically.  This all needs to occur before save/submit.  I am checking out ajax callback as suggested by tenken.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [hook_node_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7)

> Act on a node being inserted or updated.
>
> This hook is invoked from node_save() before the node is saved to the
>   database.

To attach a custom submit handler, create a custom module and do something like this:

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)
{
  if($form_id == 'form_abc')
  {
    $form['#submit'][] = "my_module_form_submit_handler";
  }
}

function my_module_form_submit_handler($form, &$form_state)
{
  drupal_set_message("The form is being submitted, do some extra stuff now...");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this advice Geoff. This appears to occur after hook_node_submit().  I think what I am needed is to stop the saving of the node so that I can present the user with some more selections (from the external DB) before they finally save/submit.

Comment: I see - this does occur after submit(), just re-read your question and realised this isn't what you're looking for after all. There is nothing before submit() - you would need to rewrite the submit handler and do whatever processing you want, and then call the core submit() to finalise things

Comment: Not even hook_form_alter then?  I wonder if this was the case in older version of drupal.  I am up for re-writing the submit handler if I can find some documentation on how to do that specific to this node content type.

Comment: hook_form_alter occurs before the form is rendered, not after its filled out - that's where you can make changes to it before the user even sees it

Comment: @geoderek I added some code to get you started on a custom submit handler

Comment: Thanks Geoff.  Stinks to keep being stuck on this.  I created function w/ the name like CUSTMODULE_form_FORM_ID_alter.  I tried putting a set message in there to see if it  even gets there. When I hit save I can't get the code within it to run.

Comment: Be sure to clear the cache or it wont find a new hook

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for sticking w/ me.  That worked.